# How to keep track of 2 related values and add new as needed?

Tags: c#, arrays, reference, integer

I have a situation where I am translating a file, and if I encounter a string of "@sometext" versus "@45" where I would use the value of 45, I need to start correlating that value as (@sometext,16) and each time I encounter "@sometext" translate it as 16, but if I then later encounter "@othertext" I would use the next incremented value (17) each time it is referenced.

Is there a simple way in C# for me to handle this type of operation? Each time I enounter "@text" check all entries for that text, and if not found, add it as an entry with the next incremented reference value?

I thought a 2D array might work, but I'm not thinking I'll be able to easily search current entries to see if text exists already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Dictionary<string, int> textDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
int initial = 16;

...

public string ReplaceText(string stringVal)
{
    if (!textDict.ContainsKey(stringVal))
        textDict.Add(stringVal, initial + textDict.Count);

    return textDict[stringVal].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abion, that was exactly the kind of thing I was looking for!